How does the order of $\mathbb{E}(X_n)$ impacts the distribution of $X_n$?
Suppose $X_n$ is a sequence of positive random variables with $\mathbb{E} X_n=f(n) = C n^\delta$ with $C>0$ and $Var(X_n)=M=\text{const}$.
What can we say about:
$$
\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n>n^{\alpha})
$$
for different values of $\alpha$?
It seems straightforward that for $\alpha > \delta$ we can say that the limit goes to 0.
Consider the Markov inequality:
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_n>n^{\alpha}) \le \frac{f(n)}{n^\alpha} \to 0
$$
What for $\alpha < \delta$ and $\alpha=\delta$?

What is the precise definition of tilde ?

@温泽海 edited, thanks

With almost the same reasoning, by Chebyshev's, you can see that the limit goes to $1$ for $\alpha < \delta$. For $\alpha = \delta$, it depends on the value of $C$ (basically $C < 1$, $C = 1$, or $C > 1$).

@VezenBU I don't see how formally Chebyshev's can be applied here. But it gives the intuition that $X_n$ would always be around $Cn^\delta$ since variance is the same across all the $X_n$. So the limit is really probably 1 because $n^\delta$ grows faster than $n^\alpha$ for $\delta > \alpha$, but I can't see how to prove it rigorously.

For sufficiently large $n$:
$$
\mathbb{P} (X_n > n^\alpha) \ge \mathbb{P}(|X_n - f(n)| \le \epsilon_n) \ge \\
\ge 1 - Var(X_n)/\epsilon_n^2
$$
with $\epsilon_n=(f(n)-n^\alpha)/2$.
Now take the limit $n\to\infty$ and you get $0$ if $\alpha \le 1/2$.
